Scaling replicas causes probe failure
I have a service (of type LoadBalancer) with port and targetPort defined as below:
ports:
    - name: ldap-port
      protocol: TCP
      port: 389
      targetPort: 389

And a deployment with containerPort set to 389. The liveness and readiness probe is configured with a tcpSocket to the port 389. Now, when the replicas is set to 1, all is well and good. But when I scale to 2, the second pod goes to CrashLoopBackOff stating that the liveness and readiness probe failed.
Is it not possible to open a socket to 2 pods on the same port?
